# MSI Z97 PC Mate refuses to let me boot from DVD

Tags: boot, motherboard, dvd, windows-installer

I start up the machine and the DVD drive gets correctly listed

```
Detected ATA/ATAPI Devices ...
SATA port 3 <harddisk>
SATA port 4 <SSD>
SATA port 6 HL-DT-ST BDDVDRW
```

So I press `F11` to get into the boot menu ... which doesn't list the drive.

[image: msi boot menu]

(If you're wondering, yes, I've set up a dual boot with ubuntu and Windows 10 [updated from 8.1].)

Went into the setup menu and changed the boot order s.t. CD/DVD and USB CD/DVD were both first (in particular, in front of disk), which did perfectly nothing, the boot disk just gets ignored.

Disabled booting from floppy (because my PC doesn't *have* a floppy drive, plus I also read elsewhere that doing so might help ... which it doesn't.)

Other than that, I did not touch the settings. (Secure Boot support is disabled)

The dvd *is* bootable, I have confirmed as much with virtualbox.

So how do I get the option to actually *boot* from it?

(note: booting from USB stick works, couldn't have installed ubuntu, otherwise)

Comment: from the screenshot it appears that you have UEFI. Unlike BIOS UEFI support booting from media with correct keys (aka secure boot). Is that enabled in your case? What CD are you trying to boot from?

Comment: @Hennes Trying to test the new Tails3 alpha build. And no, Secure Boot support is disabled (and its mode "standard", but I doubt that matters when it is disabled).

Comment: Your UEFI should have a "Legacy Boot" or something to that effect. Some OS's require the UEFI to present this to behave and be bootable.

Comment: @Linef4ult Perfect, disable windows 8 features and it will change "UEFI" to "UEFI + Legacy" and the dvd will show up. Thanks a lot. Want to make an answer out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Discovered in comments

Tails 3 Alpha is apparently incompatible with UEFI booting so "Legacy Mode" is required. For readers this can be labelled in different ways by different OEMs. This presents a more traditional BIOS to allow the live disk to boot.

In the case of the MSI Z97 PC Mate its labelled `Windows 8 Features`.